# How to use mvn:release with GitHub when projects are in subdirectory?

Tags: maven, plugins, version-control, github, release

I am trying to use mvn release plugin with my github project  https://github.com/inder123/playn-ext

The Java project is in a subdirectory of playn-ext, under playn-headless-android. To use mvn release plugin, I need to setup the scm portion of the pom. Here is what I wrote initially:

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:inder123/playn-ext.git</connection>
  <url>scm:git:git@github.com:inder123/playn-ext.git</url>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:inder123/playn-ext.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

However, mvn release (when run from playn-headless-android) fails since the project pom is not available at the top-level.

How do I configure the scm section? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a parent pom in playn-ext directory. However, mvn release only seems to commit the parent project in this case.